# Image diff preserving color for overlaying

Tags: linux, image, colors, diff, difference

I have two almost identical images, in color. I want to generate a transparent image that could be overlayed on the first image to make it look like the 2nd. All the image diff tools I've been able to find won't preserve color the way I need. Any ideas? (preferably Linux command-line)

[image: diff a]
These are the test images I'm currently working with.
[image: diff b]
Ideally the result would be something like this, but accurate to the difference. (this one can't add the shadow, and had to be rendered separately)
[image: suboptimal test]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with **ImageMagick** at the command-line as follows. I will show you the steps I took and why so that you can diverge from my answer at any point and hopefully get the exact result you want.

Here's my initial attempt:

```
magick compare 1.jpg 2.jpg result.png
```

[image]

That's a start, but unfortunately you have used JPEG so there are ugly blocking artefacts all over the place, let's remove them with some *fuzz* - ideally though, you would use a lossless PNG rather than a JPG:

```
magick compare -fuzz 10% 1.jpg 2.jpg result.png
```

[image]

Now we can see two new problems - **ImageMagick** has kindly left the original image in reduced saturation as a reference for us and the differences have been coloured in solid red. So we want to remove the original background image and change the highlight and lowlight colours to white and black to make a change mask:

```
magick compare -fuzz 10% 1.jpg 2.jpg -compose Src -highlight-color white -lowlight-color black mask.png
```

[image]

If we now take that mask and introduce it to the original image as a transparency layer, everything else will become transparent:

```
magick 1.jpg mask.png -compose CopyOpacity -composite result.png
```

[image]

---

By the way, you *could* make that into a one-liner obviating the need for an intermediate file on disk like this:

```
magick compare -fuzz 10% 1.jpg 2.jpg -compose Src -highlight-color white -lowlight-color black png: | magick 1.jpg - -compose CopyOpacity -composite result.png
```

The first `magick` generates the mask as a PNG onto its `stdout`. The second `magick` reads the mask from its `stdin` and puts that into `1.jpg` as the alpha channel:

Comment: Mark, you can do compare from convert so that you can do it all in one command line without the pipe. See `convert .... -compare ...` at https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#compare

Comment: @fmw42 That thought did occur to me but I wasn't sure how to use `-compose src` (to get rid of the desaturated background) as well as the `-compose difference` that I actually wanted to do - so I did it in 2 steps.

Comment: `@Mark` I tried and ran into an issue with highlight and lowlight. I posted an issue at https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/4312

Comment: @fmw42 Interesting- maybe it can be done with `-define compose:highlight-color=white` or something.

Comment: `@Mark` No, not that way. I think those "minus" settings will be added in a subsequent release. I think that was an oversight in creating the -compare option

Comment: I'm actually using PNG files, not sure why they were converted on upload lol. With the PNGs, I get a much better result, so I turned the fuzziness way down and it works very nicely (with the shadow included!)
https://pasteboard.co/tyY8gpYzR7Sa.png
https://pasteboard.co/yfwWfF3fHABi.png